# matrix multiplication expression

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

How to define the following expression as matrix multiplication?

$$-\sum_{i=1}^n\left[\mid e_i\mid-\exp(\sum_{j=0}^p \gamma_j X_{ij})\right]\exp(\sum_{j=0}^p \gamma_j X_{ij})X_{i.}$$

X is a matrix, e and γ are vectors

$$X_{n,p+1}$$
$$e_{n,1}$$
$$\gamma_{p+1,1}$$

Comment: The subscript on the final $X$ makes the expression unclear. Is the summation intended to produce a scalar quantity or a vector quantity?

Comment: a vector of length n.  the expression  starts with X' but I'm not sure about the rest

Comment: But if you sum that last $X$ over $i$ that leaves the $j$ index and produces a vector of length $(p+1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For typing convenience, define the vectors
$$\eqalign{
&u\in{\mathbb R}^{n},\qquad &v\in{\mathbb R}^{p+1},\qquad &y=\gamma \\
&a=|e|,\qquad &b=\exp(Xy),\qquad &c=(b-a)\odot b \\ 
}$$
where $\odot$ denotes the elementwise product, the exponential function is applied elementwise, and $(u,v)$ are vectors with all elements equal to ${\tt1}$.

Write the function in terms of these new vectors, then reduce.
$$\eqalign{
f^T &= u^T\Big(cv^T\odot X\Big) \\
 &= u^T\Big(\operatorname{Diag}(c)\,X\,\operatorname{Diag}(v)\Big) \\
 &= c^TX\,I \\
f&= X^Tc \\
 &= X^T\Big[(b-a)\odot b\Big] \\
 &= X^T\Big[\big(\exp(Xy)-|e|\big)\odot\exp(Xy)\Big] \\
}$$
where $I\in{\mathbb R}^{(p+1)\times(p+1)}$ is the identity matrix and $f\in{\mathbb R}^{p+1}$.

#### Update

Based on your comments, you have the scalar function
$$\eqalign{\phi &= \tfrac{1}{2}(b-a):(b-a)\qquad\big({\rm Frobenius\,Product}\big)}$$
and you wish to calculate its gradient and hessian. So let's do that.
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= (b-a):db \\
  &= (b-a):(b\odot X\,dy) \\
  &= b\odot(b-a):X\,dy \\
  &= c:X\,dy \\
  &= X^Tc:dy \\
g=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}
 &= X^Tc \qquad\big({\rm Gradient}\big) \\
}$$
Now let's calculate the hessian. 
$$\eqalign{
dg &= X^Tdc \\
 &= X^T\big((2b-a)\odot db\big) \\
 &= X^T\big((2b-a)\odot b\odot X\,dy\big) \\
 &= X^T(2B-A)BX\,dy \\
H=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}
 &= X^T(2B-A)BX \qquad\big({\rm Hessian}\big) \\
}$$
where $\,A=\operatorname{Diag}(a),\,B=\operatorname{Diag}(b)$.

Comment: How do I write the derivative of f?

Comment: The derivative, aka gradient, $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\right)$ will be a third-order **tensor**. I can calculate it for you, but it will likely be useless to you. Why do you want it?

Comment: f is actually gradient, I need the hessian to write the newton raphson algorithm.               the first equation was  $$\sum_{i=1}^n \biggl(|e_i|-exp(\sum_{j=0}^p \gamma_jX_{ij})\biggl)^2 $$

Comment: I got that the second derivative is  
$$\sum_i\left[2 \exp(\sum_j \gamma_j X_{ij})-|e_i|\right]\exp(\sum_j \gamma_j X_{ij})X_{i.}X_{i.}^T$$ 
both derivative are for gamma
is the matrix correct?
$$X^T diag \biggl((2exp(X\gamma)-|e|)exp(X\gamma)\biggl)X$$

Comment: Okay, now I understand that you are taking derivatives with respect to the vector $\gamma$ and not the matrix $X$. I have updated the answer and it matches the derivatives that you have found.